# Python weasyprint convert page to pdf problem!【from china】

Tags: python, css, pdf, weasyprint

I try to convert cnn.com pages to PDF by Weasyprint, it actually works but with some unfriendly, the pdf headers are always been covered with a black block, it annoys when the content are covered, does any body know how to remove the annoyed things, likes definite a CSS sheetstyle? sincerely appreciate!!!

You can repeated the problem with any article from cnn.com.

or recommend a better converting tools, I ever try pdfkit, but it cannt download the full page with 'readmore' button are always
always display, even UserAgent has been append in http headers.

Those tools works different among websites, weird

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwuoe.jpg)

Comment: Please provide an example of your code.

Comment: import weasyprint
    url = 'https://edition.cnn.com/2021/07/23/tech/taiwan-china-cybersecurity-intl- 
    hnk/index.html'
    weasyprint.HTML(url).write_pdf('1.pdf')

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

```
import weasyprint
url = 'https://edition.cnn.com/2021/07/23/tech/taiwan-china-cybersecurity- 
intl-hnk/index.html'
weasyprint.HTML(url).write_pdf('1.pdf')
```

that is my codes